# Need help proving this inequality.

Tags: inequality

## $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}}$

I think it has something to do with Harmonic mean, but can't fighre it out.

Comment: Are a,b,c,d $> 0$?

Comment: I don't see the linear algebra here.

Comment: it doesn't say that a,b,c,d >0, but let's pressume they are. can you solve it if they are?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. For example, take $a=b=2$, $c=d=1$

Comment: how about if we added a condition a,b,c,d>1 ? Would this be solvable?

Comment: @Dekac: The inequality is scale invariant, so it is also false for $a=b=4, c=d=2$.

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a+d}+\frac{1}{b+c}}$$
for positives $a$, $b$ $c$ and $d$, which is $(ac-bd)^2\geq0$.